# Math Expression Evaluator for Portable Class Library Project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I am currently using **[ILCalc](https://ilcalc.codeplex.com/) to parse and evaluate mathematical expressions with variables** in my .NET and Windows Phone library which uses shared sources files (via symbolic link) to achieve cross-project type functionality.

I would like to replace that brittle linking mechanism with a **Portable Class Library version** (which alleviates the need to have 2 separate projects with shared files). However, the ILCalc source (stable but not updated since 2010) uses methods that are not available to PCL projects (e.g., DynamicMethod).

Can anyone point me to a Portable Class Library project that provides mathematical expression evaluation with variables (e.g. 2*x + 5, where 'x' is a variable who's value is provided at runtime)?

Comment: The math parsing library [YAMP](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/YAMP) is available in a PCL version on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/YAMP.Portable/).

Comment: YAMP seems to to the trick indeed (PCL library for mathematical expressions). @AndersGustafsson, please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad YAMP works for you, Philipp. Since your question is put on hold I am not able to post an answer. But that's no problem, it's satisfactory just to be able to share the information about YAMP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, hope it suits you

http://mathosparser.codeplex.com

Comment: But this is not a PCL library, right? It is currently only available for .NET as far as I can see from the project file.